# Sum of an integer's digits

Tags: java

The question is that in a given integer `n` you have to sum its digits. For example, the sum for 111 would be 3.

Though I managed to solve the problem, I have a good feeling that this algorithm can still be improved.

```
public static int digit(int n){
    String numbers = n+"";
    int sum = 0;
    for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length(); x++){
        sum += Integer.parseInt(numbers.charAt(x)+"");
    }

    return sum;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There is an arithmetic solution to this problem, without converting to a string. It's probably what the string conversion does internally and will therefore likely be much more efficient.

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum):

> The digit sum of a number \$x\$ in base \$b\$ is given by
>   $$
> \sum_{n=0}^{\lfloor \log_b x\rfloor} \frac{1}{b^n}(x \bmod b^{n + 1} - x \bmod b^n).
> $$

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/478974/2073469) has an implementation in C# (which is very similar to Java):

> ```
> sum = 0;
> while (n != 0) {
>     sum += n % 10;
>     n /= 10;
> }
> ```

In addition, I'd like to comment on the naming of your method. In my opinion, `digit` doesn't describe its function very well. Instead I'd recommend something similar to `digitSum`.

Note that this approach doesn't handle negative numbers. They cause the function to go into an infinite loop. To handle that case, you can something like the following:

```
public static int digitSum(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    bool isNegative = false;

    if (n < 0) {
        isNegative = true;
        n *= -1;
    }

    while (n != 0) {
        sum += n % 10;
        n /= 10;
    }

    if (isNegative) {
        return -sum;
    } else {
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Your version is the fastest of the three: https://gist.github.com/coderodde/b0e15f0cdd130ba90cd222783f40c674

Comment: Your example code fails at the edge case of `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

Not that it matters since **`int`** s do not have too much digits, but you could write more efficiently:

```
public static int digitSumV2(int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    String s = Integer.toString(n);

    for (int i = 0; i != s.length(); ++i) {
        sum += s.charAt(i) - '0';
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The problem in your implementation is that you keep converting each character to a string and then parse it; and so for each character of the text representation of the input number.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public static int digit(int n){
> ```

Methods do things, so it's often clearer if they get verb names like `sum` or `sumDigits`.  A noun name like `digit` would make more sense for a variable or class name.

> ```
>     for(int x = 0; x < numbers.length(); x++){
>         sum += Integer.parseInt(numbers.charAt(x)+"");
>     }
> ```

Consider using the range based version of the `for` loop.

```
    char [] digits = numbers.toCharArray();
    for (char digit : digits) {
        sum += digit - '0';
    }
```

This also uses the more direct character conversion rather than converting the character to a string to an integer.

This probably won't be faster than your version (although fewer conversions might help), but it's shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Explanation of my downvote: I don't think this answer adds anything to the question as both pieces of advice have already been said in other answers.

Comment: @jacwah  Please point to where in the other answers are my two pieces of advice:  1.  Name methods as a verb like `sumDigit` not a noun like `digitSum`; 2.  Use a range-based `for` loop instead an iteration variable to index an array.

Comment: I also think using the foreach loop when you can is an important point. Note that `Character.getNumericValue` exists although whether it's clearer than `digit - '0'` may be debatable.